# Controlling Velocity in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, game-physics, swipe, velocity

I have managed to get a new activity to open when the user swipes up, however they have to swipe up at a certain speed to start the new activity.

Could this be because of the class velocity? Can I control it or even change it to just detect movement.

#### Code

```
public class HomePage extends AppCompatActivity {

    private GestureDetectorCompat gestureDetectorCompat;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_page);

        gestureDetectorCompat = new GestureDetectorCompat(this, new MyGestureListener());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent (MotionEvent event) {
        this.gestureDetectorCompat.onTouchEvent(event);
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    class MyGestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
        //handle 'swipe up' action only

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent event1, MotionEvent event2,
                               float velocityX, float velocityY){

            /*
            Toast.makeText (getBaseContext(),
            event1.toString() + "\n\n" +event2.toSting(),
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             */

            if (event2.getX() < event1.getX()){
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                        "Swipe Up - startActivity()",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            //switch another activity
                Intent intent = new Intent(
                        HomePage.this, New_Page.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

                return true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have managed to get a new activity to open when the user swipes up

**incorrect**

you have managed to open an Activity when the user **Flings** up, flinging has set minimum velocity (determined by the SDK class) to be counted as a fling.

If you want the app to open at a slower speed you may have to look at a more custom solution or start to look into `onScroll` of the `SimpleOnGestureListener`

Comment: Thank you!  I used onScroll instead of onFling and replaced velocity with distance.